# Woocommerce, i need to get the url, so i can get the product id from there

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, woocommerce

I am in a bit of a pickle. I need to get the ID of the product page I am on.
I am on a product page where, there is a video in the top, and when that video ends, it calls a shortcode for a modal box popup, which works just perfect, but then inside that modal popup box I need to Get the price, and the product id so that it can't automatically generate the button for add to cart.

Hope you understand the problem, I have been searching around for 3 days, and can't find anyone who can help me.

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $postid = get_the_ID();
    global $wp; 
    $current_url1 = home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request));
    $obj_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $current_url2 = get_permalink( $obj_id );
    echo $current_url2;
    $productid = url_to_postid( $current_url2 ); 
    echo $productid;
    ?>
```

This code is currently outputting the following:

```
https://kanselvvilselv.dk/modalpopupbox/dette-er-en-popup/3350
```

if i change and use $current_url1
This is what it outputs:

```
https://kanselvvilselv.dk3350
```

My problem is, I only get the URL, and the id of the plugin I am using, but I don't know how to get the URL from the product instead.

Hopefully, someone can help, and if you need more info please tell me and I will get it for you :D

Comment: `echo ltrim(strrchr('https://kanselvvilselv.dk/modalpopupbox/dette-er-en-popup/3350', '/'), '/')`  Output `3350`

Comment: Or, `preg_match('/(\d+)$/', $url, $match)`  then `$match[1] = 3350` etc.

Comment: If you are already “importing” `global $product;`, then I’d start with a var_dump of that, and see if you might not have everything you need already …

Comment: I need it to output a whole other url. the one it outputs now is from the plugin that makes the modal popup box, i need it to output outside the loop